# Cannot publish dotnet core web api app to Azure AppService

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to build, test, and deploy a .net core web api app.  I was hoping that this article titled [Build, test, and deploy .NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) would help me build, test, and deploy the app but for some reason I'm just not getting it.

I have a simple .net core 3.1 web api app.
I want to build and publish it to a virtual dir called 'api' on an Azure AppService.
I would prefer to publish using webdeploy but I will use whatever works if that is not possible.

The error I am getting on the AzureRmWebAppDeployment task is:

> No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip
> Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'Project/Feed'
    includeNuGetOrg: true

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"    /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true  /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'SubscriptionName'
    appType: 'apiApp'
    WebAppName: 'MyWebAppName'
    VirtualApplication: 'api'
    UseWebDeploy: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have output the build artifacts to folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`(which is folder `D:\a\1\a`) In your VSBuild task and dotnet publish task. So you need to set the **Package** parameter to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip` for **AzureRmWebAppDeployment** task.

See below:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'SubscriptionName'
    appType: 'apiApp'
    WebAppName: 'MyWebAppName'
    VirtualApplication: 'api'
    UseWebDeploy: true
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

If you donot specify the **Package** parameter for **AzureRmWebAppDeployment** task. The default value is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip`, which makes **AzureRmWebAppDeployment** task look for the deployment artifacts in folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` (which is folder `D:\a\1\s` in build agent) and its subfolders. Since you output the build artifacts to folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, that's why you saw the error `No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip`.

See document [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) for more information.